# Why isn't the banner updating?

Tags: java, android

```
Updated once a minute why?



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import com.qscan.qrscannerapp.R;
import com.yandex.mobile.ads.common.AdRequest;
import com.yandex.mobile.ads.common.InitializationListener;
import com.yandex.mobile.ads.banner.AdSize;
import com.yandex.mobile.ads.banner.BannerAdView;
import com.yandex.mobile.ads.common.MobileAds;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class MyAdsController {

    public static String KEY_ADS_PLATFORM = "key_ads";
    // Создайте InitializationListener
// Define the InitializationListener
    private static Timer bannerRefreshTimer;



    private static InitializationListener initializationListener = new InitializationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationCompleted() {
            // Empty implementation, no specific actions required.
        }

        // @Override
        //  public void onInitializationFailed(String error) {
        // Add your code here for what to do when initialization fails.
        //   }
    };

    public static void setTypeAds(Context ctx) {
        // Initialize the Yandex Mobile Ads SDK with the InitializationListener
        MobileAds.initialize(ctx, initializationListener);

        // Rest of your code
    }

    private static int flagAds = 1;

    public static void listenNetworkChangeToRequestAdsFull(Activity ac) {
        if (h == null)
            h = new Handler();

        if (rCheckNetworkLoadAdsInterstitial == null)
            rCheckNetworkLoadAdsInterstitial = new RCheckNetworkLoadAdsInterstitial(ac);

        h.post(rCheckNetworkLoadAdsInterstitial);
    }

    static RCheckNetworkLoadAdsInterstitial rCheckNetworkLoadAdsInterstitial;

    static boolean lastNetworkAvailable = false;

    static class RCheckNetworkLoadAdsInterstitial implements Runnable {
        Activity ac;

        public RCheckNetworkLoadAdsInterstitial(Activity ac) {
            this.ac = ac;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!lastNetworkAvailable
                    && CheckInternet.isNetworkAvailable(ac)) {
                requestNewInterstitial();
            }

            if (CheckInternet.isNetworkAvailable(ac)) {
                lastNetworkAvailable = true;
            } else {
                lastNetworkAvailable = false;
            }

            h.postDelayed(RCheckNetworkLoadAdsInterstitial.this, 4000);
        }
    }

    public static void handleInterstitialAds(final Activity ac) {
        // Ваш код обработки межстраничных объявлений
    }

    public static void requestNewInterstitial() {
        // Ваш код для запроса новых межстраничных объявлений
    }

    public static Handler h = new Handler();

    public static Runnable rAdsInterstitial = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            flagAds = 1;
            h.postDelayed(rAdsInterstitial, TIME_DELAY_ADS_INTERSTITIAL);
        }
    };

//protected static AdRequest getAdRequest() {
    // AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    //        .build();
    //return adRequest;
//}

    static final int TIME_DELAY_ADS_INTERSTITIAL = 60 * 1000 * 3;

    public static void showAdsFullBeforeDoAction(final Idelegate callback) {
        // Ваш код для показа межстраничных объявлений перед выполнением действия
    }
    private static AdSize getAdSize(Context context) {
        Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

        int adWidthPixels = outMetrics.widthPixels; // Ширина экрана в пикселях

        // Установите высоту баннера как 10% от высоты экрана
        int adHeightPixels = (int) (outMetrics.heightPixels * 0.05); // 10% от высоты экрана

        return AdSize.inlineSize(adWidthPixels, adHeightPixels);
    }
    public static void showBannerAds(final Activity ac) {
        BannerAdView adView = new BannerAdView(ac);
        AdSize fullWidthAdSize = getAdSize(ac); // Change this line to use the correct method name
        adView.setAdSize(fullWidthAdSize);
        adView.setAdUnitId("R-M-2631210-1");

        RelativeLayout layout = ac.findViewById(R.id.adView_container);
        layout.addView(adView);

        adView.loadAd(getAdRequest());
        startBannerRefreshTimer(ac, adView);
    }

    private static int dpToPx(Context context, int dp) {
        float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return Math.round(dp * density);
    }


    public static void startBannerRefreshTimer(final Activity ac, final BannerAdView adView) {
        bannerRefreshTimer = new Timer();
        bannerRefreshTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ac.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Предположим, что 'adView' - это ваш объект BannerAdView
                        refreshBanner(adView);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 31000); // 31000 миллисекунд = 31 секун
    }

    // public static InitializationListener getApplicationAdsId(Context ctx) {
    //
//}
    public static void stopBannerRefreshTimer() {
        if (bannerRefreshTimer != null) {
            bannerRefreshTimer.cancel();
            bannerRefreshTimer = null;
        }
    }

    protected static AdRequest getAdRequest() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        return adRequest;
    }

    // Метод для обновления баннера
    private static void refreshBanner(BannerAdView adView) {
        adView.loadAd(getAdRequest());
    }

    public static void releaseAdsCallbacks() {
        stopBannerRefreshTimer();
    }

    public static void releaseAds_Callbacks() {
        if (h != null)
            h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
}
```